# Horizontal pager misbehaving after the last item scroll

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-scrolling, horizontal-pager

I'm using the pageSize attribute with a fixed width of 282.dp but when scrolling after the last item the scroll takes while after returning to the normal position and if another vertical scroll happens it will stuck as stretched out (due to scrolling effect)

my pager composable

```
@Composable
fun DealsPager(
    deals: List<Deal>,
    rentalDuration: String,
    onClickDeal: (deal) -> Unit
) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = deals.size,
        state = pagerState,
        pageSize = PageSize.Fixed(282.dp), // here is the problem cause
        pageSpacing = 16.dp,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp)
    ) {
        DealItem(
            deal = deals[it],
            duration = rentalDuration,
            testTag = "deal list item $it",
            onClick = onClickDeal
        )
    }
}
```

if I try to remove the pageSize is works fine and I need a way that it works normally with fixed size for item so more than one item shown per page

Answer (score 2):

Use the column to set fixed size

```
Column(Modifier.width(282.dp)) {
    HorizontalPager(
      ...
    ) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is an error in the pageSize Property of the HorizontalPagerApi. I found a little workaround you can use.

```
 HorizontalPager(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                        beyondBoundsPageCount = 1,
                        state = pagerState
                    ) { idx ->
                        Box(modifier = Modifier
                            .width(boxWidthDp.dp)
                            .graphicsLayer {
                                val yourValue = calculateValue(idx) 
                                when (idx) {
                                    0 -> {
                                        translationX = yourValue
                                    }

                                    1 -> {
                                        translationX = yourValue
                                    }

                                    2 -> {
                                        translationX = yourValue
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ){...}
```

The Idea being that you can shift your Content to the left and right so it appears on the other screens as well. You of course have to adjust the code and add your own `calculateValue(...)` Method.